# Is it possible to setup up a TFS New Service Endpoint with ssh key for External Git

Tags: git, ssh, tfs

I'm using TFS 2015 and I'm trying to create a service endpoint for an external git repository. The new service endpoint dialog only has fields for url, username/password but I need to be able to also supply a ssh key for authentication. I've looked at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository but cannot find any helpful documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not support** by now.  I have created a **uservoice** for your, you could vote up for it, TFS Admin will kindly review it.

> **TFS New Service Endpoint with ssh key for External Git**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17736769-tfs-new-service-endpoint-with-ssh-key-for-external

Comment: If this helped, could you mark it as an answer. Any update about the **TFS New Service Endpoint with ssh key for External Git** will let you know as soon as I got it.

Comment: I just voted your ticket. we have the same problem too and don't see a user identity and password a good way to create a server to server connection that is run without a user involved.